# Discord.js как записать ник или айди использовавшего команду

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-api

Возможно-ли записать ник человека который записал команду в отдельный файл? К примеру в IDs.json.
Требуется что то по типу оставления заявки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Да, возможно! Смотрите что вам приходит при запросе, записывайте.